# How to get length of a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, readlines

So, if I have a list called myList I use `len(myList)` to find the number of elements in that list. Fine. But how do I find the number of lists in a list?

```
text = open("filetest.txt", "r")
myLines = text.readlines()
numLines=len(myLines)
print numLines
```

The above text file used has 3 lines of 4 elements separated by commas. The variable numLines prints out as '4' not '3'. So, `len(myLines)` is returning the number of elements in each list not the length of the list of lists.

When I print `myLines[0]` I get the first list, `myLines[1]` the second list, etc. But `len(myLines)` does not show me the number of lists, which should be the same as 'number of lines'.

I need to determine how many lines are being read from the file.

Comment: In your code, you have a list of lines (strings).  not a list of lists.  And python will happily count empty lines...  Did you check to make sure you don't have any empty lines?

Comment: `len(myLines)` will give you the number of objects inside that list no matter if they are lists, dicts or strings.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine. Give us the file as is.

Comment: Just `print myLines` and the reason will be clear.

Comment: Python will *not* automatically split text read from a file on commas. Use the `csv` module if you want that to happen.

Comment: If the text file used has 3 lines, `len(myLines)` will be `3` regardless of the content of each. Perhaps you have a blank line at the end of the file. Another thing to try is using `open("filetest.txt", "rt")` because some platforms have multiple characters at the end of each line of a text file which could confuse `readlines()`.

Answer (score 25):

This saves the data in a list of lists.

```
text = open("filetest.txt", "r")
data = [ ]
for line in text:
    data.append( line.strip().split() )

print "number of lines ", len(data)
print "number of columns ", len(data[0])

print "element in first row column two ", data[0][1]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce 

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [], [1, 2]]
print(reduce(lambda count, l: count + len(l), a, 0))
# result is 11
```

Answer (score 1):

"The above text file used has 3 lines of 4 elements separated by commas. The variable numLines prints out as '4' not '3'. So, len(myLines) is returning the number of elements in each list not the length of the list of lists."

It sounds like you're reading in a .csv with 3 rows and 4 columns. If this is the case, you can find the number of rows and lines by using the .split() method:

```
text = open("filetest.txt", "r").read()
myRows = text.split("\n")      #this method tells Python to split your filetest object each time it encounters a line break 
print len(myRows)              #will tell you how many rows you have
for row in myRows:
  myColumns = row.split(",")   #this method will consider each of your rows one at a time. For each of those rows, it will split that row each time it encounters a comma.  
  print len(myColumns)         #will tell you, for each of your rows, how many columns that row contains
```

Answer (score -2):

if the name of your list is `listlen` then just type `len(listlen)`. This will return the size of your list in the python.

Answer (score -2):

The method len() returns the number of elements in the list.

```
 list1, list2 = [123, 'xyz', 'zara'], [456, 'abc']
    print "First list length : ", len(list1)
    print "Second list length : ", len(list2)
```

When we run above program, it produces the following result −

First list length :  3
Second list length :  2